# Is there a kind of food like bread that I can use to absorb sauce but that doesn't dry out so fast?

Tags: bread, sauce

This is more related to eating than cooking: is there a kind of food that I can use to absorb sauce but that doesn't dry out as fast as bread?

I was thinking in the context of using bread to get the remaining sauce from a plate. And rice of pasta are par meals whereas this would be complementary to a meal.

> when you say "dry out fast" do you mean over the course of the meal, or that the loaf dries out over a few days before you can eat it all?

I mean over 1 or 2 days, which for me is a pretty short period of time, too short for it to be worth buying fresh bread ever.

> Depending on the meal, would thick cut chips be a suitable substitute? (UK chips FYI)

Yes I guess it could work, although not as well because chips don't absorb as well as bread, but it does take more effort and time to prepare. I had something easier in mind but I realize that what I'm looking for might not exist.

I was thinking of something like **indian naan bread** but I'm not sure that it is much better at staying fresh...

Comment: What's wrong with bread?

Comment: when you say "dry out fast" do you mean over the course of the meal, or that the loaf dries out over a few days before you can eat it all?

Comment: Depending on the meal, would thick cut chips be a suitable substitute? (UK chips FYI)

Comment: @GdD there is nothing wrong with bread, it has nourished civilizations for ten thousand years, this is entirely a "first world problem" I believe kids call it these days

Comment: Any reason you can't use the preservative laden breads that last over a week? I know the quality isn't as good, but it has the longevity you desire.

Comment: Bread rolls might keep better, or buy them singly, or freeze them. Are they available where you live?

Comment: Naan bread dry out quickly.

Comment: BTW, where are you? My answer is a little UK-centric but should make sense in much of Europe and North America. I would have written it slightly differently for France, Germany, Canada or the USA, to account for differences in availability

Comment: I am in Switzerland and all the things you mentioned are accessible, thanks for the great answer! I think bread rolls and part baked bread are a good option. I have bought toast bread (the soft kind that's "processed" and has a square shape) for some time but I think it's not super healthy.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few ideas, starting with how you can make bread work, based on my comment:

*Bread rolls* often keep better than loaves, because they have a crust all round. You can often buy them singly. Demi baguettes are similar but about twice the size.

*Part baked* rolls keep for months (sealed, once open keep in the fridge and use within a few days). You finish cooking them just before serving, which is easy if you've got the oven on anyway.

*Bread freezes well*, at least for short periods, as does home made dough. You could form it into rolls, freeze, defrost in the fridge, and bake twice a week.

Many of these ideas require using an oven. If you don't have one or don't want to use it daily, you still have the option of *flatbreads*. Chapatis, for example, are intended to eat sauce with, and cook in a dry frying pan. They're simple to make fresh or, as with flour tortillas, you can buy or make a batch, keep in the fridge, and reheat in a microwave. You can often find prepacked flatbreads in 2-serving packs; until opened they keep for weeks, after that, seal them up and you've got a couple of days.

If bread is getting a little dry, *toasting* it makes it nicer (especially if you melt butter with crushed garlic and spread that on it).

Moving away from bread, rice and pasta don't really absorb much sauce, but *couscous* does (especially if you are a little mean with the water when cooking it. Boiled, jacket, or even roast *potatoes* can be mashed into gravy with your fork.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Frozen waffles.**  These are great in so many ways.  They come in big boxes and stay good a long time.  Toast some up when you need them as sauce mops.  Also they make a good PB&J.

**2.  Corn flakes.**  I keep corn flakes for putting under chili or beans.

**3.  Pancakes.**  It is really easy to whip up some pancakes.  Scratch pancakes are so easy if you generally have those ingredients on hand: flour, baking powder, oil, milk, sour cream or yogurt or kefir.  Pancakes are as thirsty for sauce as they are for syrup and fresh pancakes are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you start with something very dry such as crackers, it should hold on to moisture well. Keep sealed in a refrigirator.

You can also do the same trick with drying the bread in an oven and using it like that.